# Nested loops in xslt 1.0 with unique values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml as input...

```
    <ns0:Root xmlns:ns0="http://testing">
    <DetailRecord>
        <Upc>1</Upc>
        <UnitCost>111.111</UnitCost>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord>
        <Upc>1</Upc>
        <UnitCost>111.222</UnitCost>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord>
        <Upc>1</Upc>
        <UnitCost>111.222</UnitCost>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord>
        <Upc>2</Upc>
        <UnitCost>111.333</UnitCost>
    </DetailRecord>
    <DetailRecord>
        <Upc>3</Upc>
        <UnitCost>111.111</UnitCost>
    </DetailRecord>
</ns0:Root>
```

I am trying to generate the following output...

```
1
   111.111
   111.222
2
   111.333
3
   111.111
```

Each "Upc" value should be distinct in the output. Underneath the "Upc" should be a list of distinct "UnitCost" values. I have tried multiple variations with no such luck. My latest iteration is as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="upcNum" match="//DetailRecord/Upc" use="./text()"/>
    <xsl:key name="cst" match="UnitCost" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="//DetailRecord/Upc[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('upcNum',.))]">
                    <xsl:sort select="."/>
                    <xsl:variable name="myUpc" select="."/> 
                    <h1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                    </h1>

                    <xsl:for-each select="//DetailRecord[Upc=current()]/UnitCost">
                        <div><xsl:value-of select="current()" /></div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is incorrect as it generates output where the "UnitCost" is not distinct. The output I receive is as follows...

```
1
   111.111
   111.222
   111.222
2
   111.333
3
   111.111
```

How can I correctly achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Don't use `//` - especially in the nested loop

Comment: scratch that. I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've correctly identified this as a grouping problem and are using Muenchian Grouping, which is good! But in this instance, you are doing two lots of grouping, once on just **Upc** and then on **UnitCost** within each **Upc** instance.

To start with, for the grouping on just **Upc** your key is fine, but it might make things simpler to consider grouping the **DetailRecord** elements by **Upc**, and define the key like so. The main point to not is you do not need to specify the full xpath to the **DetailRecord** here, the key will pick up the element wherever it is in the document (You would only need to worry about specifying a path if you did want to restrict what was selected)

```
<xsl:key name="upcNum" match="DetailRecord" use="Upc"/>
```

In terms of grouping the **UnitCost** elements for each distinct **Upc** element, you need a compound key here...

```
<xsl:key name="cst" match="DetailRecord" use="concat(Upc, '|', UnitCost)"/>
```

The `|` can actually be any character here, just as long as it doesn't appear in either of the values you are concatenating.

With this key, to get the distinct **UnitCost** elements for a distinct **Upc** you would simply do this (It's just muenchian grouping again).

```
<xsl:for-each 
     select="key('upcNum', Upc)
             [generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('cst',concat(Upc, '|', UnitCost)))]">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="upcNum" match="DetailRecord" use="Upc"/>
    <xsl:key name="cst" match="DetailRecord" use="concat(Upc, '|', UnitCost)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="//DetailRecord[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('upcNum', Upc))]">
                    <xsl:sort select="."/>
                    <xsl:variable name="myUpc" select="."/> 
                    <h1>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Upc" />
                    </h1>

                    <xsl:for-each select="key('upcNum', Upc)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('cst',concat(Upc, '|', UnitCost)))]">
                        <div><xsl:value-of select="UnitCost" /></div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```